# Trigonometry on a centred anchor point

Tags: objective-c, math, sprite-kit

**Problem**

I'm trying to get an aim-angle to trace a moving sprite, whilst the sprite tracing is also moving. The problem is, with a centred anchor point.. How is it possible to create triangles between them

For example, if the screen centre is 0, 0 on `.position` how is it possible to create a triangle between them if for instance, the player position is `-100,-100` and the enemy position is `100,100`

I ask this, because my tracing only works if the player is in position `0,0` as the next bit of code fails.

```
//get position of enemy
CGPoint enemyPosition = enemy.position;
//get current aim angle, position, aim position of enemy
CGPoint currentPlayerPosition = player.position;

float adjacent = currentPlayerPosition.y + enemyPosition.y;
float opposite = currentPlayerPosition.x + enemyPosition.x;
```

adjacent & opposite will be the value of 0 if -100 player and +100 enemy..?

So how does one alter this?

```
float newAngle = atan2f(opposite, adjacent);

newAngle = ((newAngle) * (180.0 / M_PI));
```

That would be perfect if the players position is `x:0,y:0` however, if anything else, it doesn't work at all. Trying to draw a triangle between them when playing in -figures is frying my brain!

Answer (score 0):

```
float adjacent = fabs(currentPlayerPosition.y - enemyPosition.y);
float opposite = fabs(currentPlayerPosition.x - enemyPosition.x);
```

I needed absolutes, when I programmed it, I did it from centre screen.. Re-Reading my question helped me answer it.. I think I need a rubber duck!

```
if (currentPlayerPosition.x > enemyPosition.x) {
    opposite = opposite * -1;
}
if (currentPlayerPosition.y > enemyPosition.y) {
    adjacent = adjacent * -1;
}
```

Fixes the issue.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `dx = enemyPosition.x - currentPlayerPosition.x` and `dy = enemyPosition.y - currentPlayerPosition.y`, without the `fabs`, and `angle = atan2(dy, dx)`?

Comment: @0x141E Wouldn't that give me the exact issue I was facing in the first place if you swapped their positions? Using absolutes to get the difference between the numbers is working for drawing triangles between them no matter the position.